# Row Referencing in R data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have the following sample dataset:

```
iris <- data.table(iris)[c(1:5,51:55,101:105), list(ID=.I, Species,Sepal.Length)]
```

Then say that I want to calculate the absolute difference between rows within a group (in this case, `Species`).

```
iris[ , SL.Diff := c(NA,abs(diff(Sepal.Length))) , by = Species]
```

At this point, I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
   ID    Species Sepal.Length SL.Diff
1:  1     setosa          5.1      NA
2:  2     setosa          4.9     0.2
3:  3     setosa          4.7     0.2
4:  4     setosa          4.6     0.1
5:  5     setosa          5.0     0.4
6:  6 versicolor          7.0      NA
```

Now I want to calculate a new variable `Sepal.Length2` that takes on the next row's value if `SL.Diff` is less than a threshold of 0.3.

```
iris[ , Sepal.Length2 := ifelse(SL.Diff < 0.3, iris[ID+1]$Sepal.Length, Sepal.Length)]
```

This works the way I want it to.  But what if I want to do the same comparison but instead of taking on the next row, I want to take on the value of the previous row?

```
iris[ , Sepal.Length3 := ifelse(SL.Diff < 0.3, iris[ID-1]$Sepal.Length, Sepal.Length)]
```

`Sepal.Length3` does not give the output that I was expecting.  Anyone know what I could be doing wrong here?

```
    ID    Species Sepal.Length SL.Diff Sepal.Length2 Sepal.Length3
 1:  1     setosa          5.1      NA            NA            NA
 2:  2     setosa          4.9     0.2           4.7           4.9
 3:  3     setosa          4.7     0.2           4.6           4.7
 4:  4     setosa          4.6     0.1           5.0           4.6
 5:  5     setosa          5.0     0.4           5.0           5.0
 6:  6 versicolor          7.0      NA            NA            NA
 7:  7 versicolor          6.4     0.6           6.4           6.4
 8:  8 versicolor          6.9     0.5           6.9           6.9
 9:  9 versicolor          5.5     1.4           5.5           5.5
10: 10 versicolor          6.5     1.0           6.5           6.5
11: 11  virginica          6.3      NA            NA            NA
12: 12  virginica          5.8     0.5           5.8           5.8
13: 13  virginica          7.1     1.3           7.1           7.1
14: 14  virginica          6.3     0.8           6.3           6.3
15: 15  virginica          6.5     0.2            NA           5.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.table.[` evaluates `i` and `j` in the scope of the data.table in question.

Therefore

`iris[ID+1]$Sepal.Length` evaulates `ID` in the scope of `iris` (for a second time).

Your issue really arises because you are creating a `0` index (which is silently dropped by `R`)

```
a <- c('a','b')
a[0:1]
# [1] "a"
 a[1]
# [1] "a"
```

So, you need to deal better with "known NA values" and implied NA values.

Here is an approach

```
# calculate the "threshold" column
iris[,thresh := SL.Diff <0.3]
# where does it need to go "up" and what indexed value need it go up by
iris[!is.na(thresh), up := ifelse(thresh, ID+1L,ID)]
# create the column
iris[, S2 := Sepal.Length[up]]
# the same for "down"

iris[!is.na(thresh), down := ifelse(thresh, ID-1L,ID)]
iris[, S3 := Sepal.Length[down]]

iris
# ID       Species Sepal.Length SL.Diff thresh up  S2 down  S3
# 1:  1      setosa          5.1      NA     NA NA  NA   NA  NA
# 2:  2      setosa          4.9     0.2   TRUE  3 4.7    1 5.1
# 3:  3      setosa          4.7     0.2   TRUE  4 4.6    2 4.9
# 4:  4      setosa          4.6     0.1   TRUE  5 5.0    3 4.7
# 5:  5      setosa          5.0     0.4  FALSE  5 5.0    5 5.0
# 6:  6  versicolor          7.0      NA     NA NA  NA   NA  NA
# 7:  7  versicolor          6.4     0.6  FALSE  7 6.4    7 6.4
# 8:  8  versicolor          6.9     0.5  FALSE  8 6.9    8 6.9
# 9:  9  versicolor          5.5     1.4  FALSE  9 5.5    9 5.5
# 10: 10 versicolor          6.5     1.0  FALSE 10 6.5   10 6.5
# 11: 11  virginica          6.3      NA     NA NA  NA   NA  NA
# 12: 12  virginica          5.8     0.5  FALSE 12 5.8   12 5.8
# 13: 13  virginica          7.1     1.3  FALSE 13 7.1   13 7.1
# 14: 14  virginica          6.3     0.8  FALSE 14 6.3   14 6.3
# 15: 15  virginica          6.5     0.2   TRUE 16  NA   14 6.3
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure of the speed implications of this, but here's another attempt:

```
# make a column of the next values using head()
iris[, S3 := c(NA,head(Sepal.Length,-1)), by=Species]
# overwrite those values not meeting your criteria with the original values
iris[ !(SL.Diff < 0.3), S3 := Sepal.Length]

iris
#    ID    Species Sepal.Length SL.Diff  S3
# 1:  1     setosa          5.1      NA  NA
# 2:  2     setosa          4.9     0.2 5.1
# 3:  3     setosa          4.7     0.2 4.9
# 4:  4     setosa          4.6     0.1 4.7
# 5:  5     setosa          5.0     0.4 5.0
# 6:  6 versicolor          7.0      NA  NA
# 7:  7 versicolor          6.4     0.6 6.4
# 8:  8 versicolor          6.9     0.5 6.9
# 9:  9 versicolor          5.5     1.4 5.5
#10: 10 versicolor          6.5     1.0 6.5
#11: 11  virginica          6.3      NA  NA
#12: 12  virginica          5.8     0.5 5.8
#13: 13  virginica          7.1     1.3 7.1
#14: 14  virginica          6.3     0.8 6.3
#15: 15  virginica          6.5     0.2 6.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think dplyr makes this a little easier to express by providing `lead()` and `lag()` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
iris2 <- iris[c(1:5, 51:55, 101:105), c("Species", "Sepal.Length")]
names(iris2) <- c("species", "sepal")
iris2$id <- 1:15

iris2 %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(
    thres = abs(sepal - lag(sepal)),
    up =   ifelse(thres < 0.3, lead(sepal), sepal),
    down = ifelse(thres < 0.3, lag(sepal), sepal)
  )
```